# Perl: how do I match a pattern like this?

Tags: regex, perl

Say there are two words like: googleweb.us and google.us

This is one way I worked out to match these in a single regex, but it looks ugly.

```
/(google|espn|foxtel)\w*[web\.\w+|\.\w+]/
```

I only want to cover both of the two cases when "web" exists or not. How could the pattern could be improved?

Comment: Your regex covers more than what your question asks about; what are you really after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow "web" to be optional for just google:

```
/(google(web)?|espn|foxtel)\.\w+/
```

This will allow "web" to be optional for any of the domains:

```
/(google|espn|foxtel)(web)?\.\w+/
```

Comment: Ha, smart, match 0 or 1 time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to revise your 'character class'.  The material in square brackets is treated as a character class, and isn't what you had in mind.

A regex that would match what you ask about in words ('`googleweb.us`' and '`google.us`') is:

```
/^(google)(web)?\.us$/
```

When you've defined what else you want it to match, people can refine the regex.